# How to pass ScrollPane event KEY_PRESSED, KeyCode.LEFT to parent pane?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I have a StackPane with a single child - ScrollPane. I am trying to handle KEY_PRESSED, KeyCode.LEFT (just an example, I want to handle every arrow key) event on StackPane.
As I am concerned the particular event is consumed on ScrollPane. I would like to prevent that but cannot find any reasonable way.

Answer (score 2):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventDispatcher;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ScrollPaneDispatcherApp extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
        stackPane.setStyle("-fx-backgound-color: red");

        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow");

        stackPane.getChildren().add(scrollPane);

        Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        scrollPane.requestFocus();

        EventDispatcher sceneEventDispatcher = scene.getEventDispatcher();
        EventDispatcher stackPaneEventDispatcher = stackPane.getEventDispatcher();
        EventDispatcher scrollPaneEventDispatcher = scrollPane.getEventDispatcher();

        scene.setEventDispatcher((event, tail) -> {
            if (KeyEvent.ANY.equals(event.getEventType().getSuperType())) {
                System.out.println("DISPATCH\tScene\t\tevent=" + event.getEventType());
            }
            return sceneEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(event, tail);
        });

        stackPane.setEventDispatcher((event, tail) -> {
            if (KeyEvent.ANY.equals(event.getEventType().getSuperType())) {
                System.out.println("DISPATCH\tStackPane\tevent=" + event.getEventType());
            }
            return stackPaneEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(event, tail);
        });

        scrollPane.setEventDispatcher((event, tail) -> {
            if (KeyEvent.ANY.equals(event.getEventType().getSuperType())) {
                System.out.println("DISPATCH\tScrollPane\tevent=" + event.getEventType());
            }
            Event eventToDispatch = scrollPaneEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(event, tail);
            if (KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED.equals(event.getEventType())) {
                if (KeyCode.LEFT.equals(((KeyEvent) event).getCode()) || KeyCode.RIGHT.equals(((KeyEvent) event).getCode())) {
                    if (eventToDispatch == null) {
                        return event;
                    }
                }
            }
            return eventToDispatch;
        });

        scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.ANY,
                event -> System.out.println("FILTER\t\tScene\t\tevent=" + event.getEventType()));
        stackPane.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.ANY,
                event -> System.out.println("FILTER\t\tStackPane\tevent=" + event.getEventType()));
        scrollPane.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.ANY,
                event -> System.out.println("FILTER\t\tScrollPane\tevent=" + event.getEventType()));

        scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.ANY,
                event -> System.out.println("HANDLER\t\tScene\t\tevent=" + event.getEventType()));
        stackPane.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.ANY,
                event -> System.out.println("HANDLER\t\tStackPane\tevent=" + event.getEventType()));
        scrollPane.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.ANY,
                event -> System.out.println("HANDLER\t\tScrollPane\tevent=" + event.getEventType()));
    }
}
```

Proposed solution overrides LEFT, RIGHT arrows KEY_PRESSED events consumption behaviour for ScrollPane. The clue is the new EventDispatcher for ScrollPane. Rest of the code is only for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the ScrollPane will consume the key press event and the StackPane will not.

If you want to intercept a key press using a parent pane event handler, then you should use an event filter (https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/filters.htm) to do so (to intercept the event during the capturing phase rather than the bubbling phase).

Read up on event processing (https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/processing.htm) if you need to understand the capturing versus bubbling concepts.

From docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/filters.htm : Event filters enable the parent node to provide common processing for its child nodes or to intercept an event and prevent child nodes from acting on the event

Comment: You are right about the phase I should use but it is not my code I'm altering and I was just trying to fit in. After a cosideration I will have to change the whole thing. Just out of pure curiosity, do you know any way to unconsume event?

Comment: Are you writing the code for the parent or the child?
If you are writing the code for the parent, in this case the StackPane, then you should be able to add an event filter to it. 
From https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/filters.htm :
Event filters enable the parent node to provide common processing for its child nodes or to intercept an event and prevent child nodes from acting on the event.

Comment: I'm altering key events handling for the whole app so my choice will be filtering key events on window.

Comment: After a consideration it is a very bad idea to handle app key shortcut events with filtering. I want to run shortcut action only if event was not consumed. Let's imagine text filed and filtering. It makes no sense. While writing text field value I would fire many shortcuts actions. That is why the handler is the right place to do it, so my question stands still - how to unconsume event?

Comment: Once consumed, the event is gone. There is no way to bring it back. I also doesn't make any sense to use a shortcut for the application which uses a key combination while typing inside a textfield. Doesn't it make more sense first losing focus from the textfield and then doing the shortcut?